# keep history of connected clients to a web-service jax-ws

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, jax-ws

I have a multi player game and I want to keep history of connected players to understand when should game start .
I used HttpSession But it can't solve my problem.
also I created a static ArrayList of players in webservices but it couldn't solve my poblem . :(
Any other idea ?

```
     @Resource
    private WebServiceContext wsContext;    
   @WebMethod
    public PlayerModel connect(String PlayerName) {
        PlayerModel playerModel = null;
        Players players = new Players() ;
        ArrayList<PlayerModel> playerList = players.getPlayers();

        if (playerList.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("from service :No payer yet");
             boardModel = new BoardModel(6, 7);
            session.setAttribute("boardModel", boardModel);



            boardModel.setPlayer1(PlayerName);
            playerModel = new PlayerModel(1, PlayerName, boardModel);
            playerList.add(playerModel) ;
        } else if (playerList.size() == 1) {
            boardModel.setPlayer2(PlayerName);
            playerModel = new PlayerModel(2, PlayerName, boardModel);
          playerList.add(playerModel) ;
        }
        return playerModel;

    }
```

another approach

```
 @Resource
 private WebServiceContext wsContext;   
 BoardModel boardModel;
 HttpSession session;

@WebMethod
public PlayerModel connect(String PlayerName) {
    MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();
    session = ((HttpServletRequest) mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST)).getSession();

    if (session == null) {
        System.out.println("from service :No payer yet");
         boardModel = new BoardModel(6, 7);
         session.setAttribute("boardModel", boardModel);
        boardModel.setPlayer1(PlayerName);
        playerModel = new PlayerModel(1, PlayerName, boardModel);
       session.setAttribute("1", playerModel);
    } else if (session.getAttribute("1" != null) {
        boardModel.setPlayer2(PlayerName);
        playerModel = new PlayerModel(2, PlayerName, boardModel);
        session.setAttribute("2", playerModel);
    }
    System.out.println("from service  : player" + PlayerName);
    return playerModel;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to add up in multiple places.

1. Your first code block, apart from missing important bits, couldn't possibly work across multiple requests.

   - `playerList` looks like it'll almost always be empty
2. A session-aware JAX-WS service by itself wouldn't help you. The session, by definition is relating to a single user. Without extra legwork on your part, there's no way for one user's webservice session to be shared across multiple users

---

The one glaring gap in your code is that **you're not identifying *an instance of the game***. **When a player requests to connect, they should be requesting to either connect to an existing game or to create one, by passing a `gameId`**. Without a token identifying a specific game, you'll struggle to connect multiple users to the same game. `connect` should have the (overly simplistic) signature `connect(String gameId, String playerName)`. A list of `gameIds` can be managed by a DAO, outside of the context of the webservice endpoint. This way, returning players or new players can make their presence known by presenting a known `gameId`, and you can keep track of connected users to a specific `gameId`